# Changing location of web.xml of my application in tomcat application

Tags: java, tomcat

I want to change the location of web.xml file of a tomcat web application.

Let's say from, WEB-INF/web.xml to web/WEB-INF/web.xml.

What changes I need to make in context ?

I have tried making context file of my project and then update the tag. Then too, it's not working

Comment: the web.xml location `WEB-INF/web.xml` is a JEE standard. You **cannot** change this - why do you want to?

Comment: @JoseK - Your comment should be posted as the answer - up votes ahoy!

Comment: Actually, I wanted to run eclipce's project structure into tomcat. (I know, after I deploy war in Tpmcat I would get that structure, but I wanted to have structure during development phase and with src)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As in the comments,

The location of web.xml is a servlet standard and **HAS** to be `WEB-INF/web.xml`

You cannot change this on any app server and we'd like to know what reason you would want to?

Some varying documentation for your info:

[Resin](http://www.caucho.com/resin-3.0/config/webapp.xtp)

> WEB-INF/web.xml contains a top-level web-app element. It is the
>   Servlet standard location for defining things like servlet mappings
>   and security roles.

[Google App Engine](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/webxml)

> Java web applications use a deployment descriptor file to determine
>   how URLs map to servlets, which URLs require authentication, and other
>   information. This file is named web.xml, and resides in the app's WAR
>   under the WEB-INF/ directory. web.xml is part of the servlet standard
>   for web applications.

and [even Wikipedia !](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deployment_descriptor)

> For web applications, the deployment descriptor must be called web.xml
>   and must reside in the WEB-INF directory in the web application root

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the reasons not to do this...

if you want to use an alternative web descriptor, perhaps because 2 web applications have a common code base but expose different servlets or whatever use setAltDDName on the Context.

e.g.

```
<Context docBase="webappname" altDDName="webapps/webappname/WEB-INF/web-alternative.xml">
```